# Do people with chromesthesia and tinnitus see the "ringing" caused by tinnitus?

Tags: synesthesia, tinnitus

Do people with [chromesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromesthesia) and [tinnitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus) see the "ringing" caused by tinnitus?

Comment: Why tag [tag:stress]? Do you only want to focus on stress-induced tinnitus? From Wikipedia: "Tinnitus...can result from a wide range of underlying causes. The most common cause is noise-induced hearing loss. Other causes include: neurological damage (multiple sclerosis), ear infections, oxidative stress, emotional stress, foreign objects in the ear, nasal allergies that prevent (or induce) fluid drain, wax build-up, and exposure to loud sounds. Withdrawal from benzodiazepines...sensorineural hearing loss or congenital hearing loss...certain medications (ototoxic tinnitus)."

Comment: @nick every kind of tinnitus is fine (for the question...)

Comment: Yes, I do see my ears ringing. All vibrations have color.

Comment: Yes. When it's quiet and all I hear is ringing, it's a very familiar head space that I can't share with anyone else. Been with me all of my life but varies in intensity.

Comment: At the very least I do, yes. The different types of ringing are mostly the same color, but shape and texture tend to vary a lot.

Comment: @mmmd thx for sharing that. Sounds acceptable...